How to remove tags from FiftyOne persistent dataset?
I added sample tags to a FiftyOne persistent dataset ("train", "test", "val"), as shown in the example here:    https://docs.voxel51.com/api/fiftyone.utils.random.html (# Generate a random sample and encode results via tags).
dataset = fo.load_dataset(dataset_name)
view = (dataset.match(F("max_similarity") < 0.9))
four.random_split(view, {"train": 0.7, 
                            "test": 0.2, 
                            "val": 0.1})

However, I made a mistake in the proportions and would like to remove these tags.
I found something about untaging a dataset in the FiftyOne doc https://docs.voxel51.com/api/fiftyone.core.clips.html?highlight=untag#fiftyone.core.clips.ClipsView.untag_labels.
I tried view.untag_labels("train"), and expected the tag to disappear but according to FiftyOne desktop app it's still here:

Here is the code I wrote to delete tags:
dataset = fo.load_dataset(dataset_name)
view = (dataset.match(F("max_similarity") < 0.9))
view.untag_labels("train", "sample tags")
view.untag_labels("val", "sample tags")
view.untag_labels("test", "sample tags")

I also tried view.untag_labels("train"), view.tags.pop() and dataset.untag_labels("train").
Thanks in advance for your answers!

I found the answer in the doc: https://docs.voxel51.com/api/fiftyone.core.clips.html#fiftyone.core.clips.ClipsView.untag_samples
view.untag_samples("train")


In FiftyOne, tags can be added on 3 distinct levels:

Dataset-level as in dataset.tags
Sample-level as in dataset.first().tags (tags on first sample)
Label-level as in dataset.first().ground_truth.detections[0].tags (tags on the first "ground-truth" detections label on the first sample).

The method untag_labels() that you originally used is meant for removing tags from the label-level. As you correctly identified, untag_samples() is the appropriate method for removing tags from the sample-level.

Thanks for the distinction, I know understand tags well better.
